# Adding a blank line in algorithm2e

Tags: line-breaking, algorithm2e

Is there any way to add a blank line in [algorithm2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)?

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
i = 1 + j\\
% I would like to add a \linebreak here
j = 1 + i\\
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

I would like to have:

[image]

If I add `\\` or `\linebreak` between `i = 1 + j\\` and `j = 1 + i\\` I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: As a workaround you can add ``\mbox{}\\`` or may be easier to type (but less *clean*) ``~\\``.

Comment: @Manuel Indeed `\mbox{}\\ ` and `~\\ ` do the trick (I had tried `~\`, forgot to add another `\` :/). Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)'s line-ending macro is `\;`. From the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf):

> **9.1 global code typesetting commands**
>
> `\;` marks the end of a line. **Don’t forget it!** By default, it prints a ‘`;`’. You can change this with `\DontPrintSemicolon`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\DontPrintSemicolon 
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  $i = 1 + j$\;
  \;
  $j = 1 + i$
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 31):

Instead of the `\DontPrintSemicolon` trick you should use `\BlankLine`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\DontPrintSemicolon 
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  $i = 1 + j$\;
  \BlankLine
  $j = 1 + i$
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a screen shot in order to 'prove' that your solution works?

Comment: Running you code I get the image added to you post - thus this does not seem to answer the question posed.

Comment: Sry. I just read the "blank line" and totaly overlooked that there should be an enumeration at the beginning of the line. So my answer is totaly wrong. Sry for that.

Comment: Upvoting for `\BlankLine` since it plays nice with line numbering.

Comment: This definitely looks better.

Comment: Is there some way to edit the size of `\BlankLine`? Could not find anything about it in the CTAN docs. I'm using now multiple `\BlankLine`s to achieve the desired result—does not look nice, though.